# PHP Unit Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker

Tags: php, unit-testing, joomla, phpunit, hhvm

I'm having an issue with php unit on hhvm where getmock() failing on phpunit 4.8.27 for a class with the following message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker::getTableColumns() in /joomla-cms/libraries/joomla/table/table.php on line 241

Test Code failing is located at https://github.com/photodude/joomla-cms/blob/patch-1/tests/unit/suites/libraries/cms/installer/JInstallerAdapterTest.php#L111
for the test code this "fails/errors" the test with no Fatal error

```
$mockTableExtension = $this->getMock('JTableExtension', array('find', 'load'), array($this->getMockDatabase()));
```

but if I use the stored value

```
$mockDatabase = $this->getMockDatabase();
```

and type cast the `mockDatabase` object to array I get the Fatal error listed above.

```
$mockTableExtension = $this->getMock('JTableExtension', array('find', 'load'), (array) $mockDatabase);
```

Travis test with the `mockDatabase` object and object type cast to array var_dumped https://travis-ci.org/photodude/joomla-cms/jobs/172201634#L1427-L2178

Everything passes and works just fine in php, the issue is specific to testing on hhvm
Am I doing something wrong in the mock setup? or is there something else going on?

note: I recently tested this portion of the test suit on php unit 5.6 and got the same issue. So I'm not sure what we've don't wrong in the setup of these tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is some issue with `array($this->getMockDatabase())` in one of the tests on hhvm. Replacing `array($this->getMockDatabase())` with `array(self::$driver)` all of the issues were resolved.

I also replaced the direct use of `getMock` with the `getMockBuilder` (for compatibility with phpunit 5.6)